# How to get program argument in a Linux shell script when also using getopts?

Tags: linux, shell, getopts

So I have a script where I want to process options with `getopts` but I also want to read arguments to the program itself in the usual way. So in this example script, I want to process the options and then `echo` the argument, given like `./script.sh -abc theargument`. The problem that arises is that I don't know which shell argument is it. Argument isn't supposed to be related to the options, so you can call the script like `./script.sh theargument` as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

while getopts "abc" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) echo "option a" ;;
        b) echo "option b" ;;
        c) echo "option c" ;;
    esac
done

echo # what?
```

I can't just `shift` arguments with `$OPTIND` to make it `$1` because options can be given like `-abc`, `-a -b -c`, `-ab -c` etc., so number of options doesn't correspond to the number of arguments.

Ideally I'd want to avoid bashisms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` way is to use *indirection* with `${!VARIABLE}` - what `VARIABLE` expands to is treated as the parameter to use, so `echo "${!OPTIND}"` after the while loop in your example would display `theargument`.

The more generic way is to use `shift` to discard the option arguments and then use `$1` etc.:

```
if [ "$OPTIND" -gt 1 ]; then
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))
fi
```

In your example `$OPTIND` is 2 after the loop, so this will shift the positional parameters left by 1, discarding the `-abc` and leaving `theargument` in `$1`. This approach works if you use `-abc theargument`, `-ab -c theargument`, `-a -b -c theargument`, and so on.